# Call to undefined function redirectToCheckout() Pliso

Tags: php, laravel

I Installed Pliso laravel package as instructions from git hub
But I get Call to undefined function redirectToCheckout() error

My code :

```
$plisioGateway = new Payment(config('plisio.api_key'));
$data = array(
    'order_name' => 'Order #' . $name, //Merchant internal order name.
    'order_number' => $name,           //Merchant internal order number. Must be a unique number in your store for each new store`s order.
    'description' => "Invoice #".$name,    //Optional order description.
    'source_amount' => number_format($order->invoice_total, 8, '.', ''),  //Invoice total float value in fiat currency.
    'source_currency' => 'USD',         //Fiat currency code. For example: USD, BRL, CAD etc.
    'cancel_url' => 'https://examplestore.com/failedOrder.php?id=' . $name,  //User will be redirected to this link in a case of invoice payment failure.
    'callback_url' => 'https://examplestore.com/callback.php',       //The link to which you will receive a notification about a change in the status of the order.
    'success_url' => 'https://examplestore.com/successOrder.php?id=' . $name,  //User will be redirected to this link in a case of invoice payment success.
    'email' => auth()->user()->email,     //User's email. If not specified user will be asked to enter his email on the invoice page.
    'plugin' => 'laravelSdk',                         //Payment gateway origin. This value will help Plisio to analyse any problem occurred with SDK functionality.
    'version' => '1.0.0'                              //Consider updating this setting every time you update the functionality related to this sdk.
);
//Create invoice and put response to the $response variable.
$response = $plisioGateway->createTransaction($data);
//Check the response and, depending on the result, redirect the user to Plisio for further payment or return to the checkout page with an error.
if ($response && $response['status'] !== 'error' && !empty($response['data'])) {
    redirect($response['data']['invoice_url']);
    clearCart();
} else {
    $errorMessage = implode(',', json_decode($response['data']['message'], true));
    redirectToCheckout();
}
```

I search the code but ok

Comment: Seems like the Plisio team is messing around, there are no method in the package itself called `redirectToCheckout` so most likely they are writing it as a pseudocode in the package demo.

Comment: Yeah, previous comment absolutely right. [package](https://github.com/Plisio/plisio-sdk-laravel) does not provide functions `clearCart`  and `redirectToCheckout`. This is just a placeholder where you will need to implement your own code.